# Filter against an edge property using a property from it's vertex

Tags: charts, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Apologies if I'm not clear, I'm new to graph databases & gremlin.

I'm using Azure Cosmos, which has some limitations.  I can't use sack for example.

I've created a gremlify sample https://gremlify.com/v19w2qtiu3i/2.

If the starting vertex is above the vertex/edge in the traversal and the lower edge in the tree has hideFromParentLevels set to true, then I want to exclude it from the results.  However if the starting vertex is at the level of the edge then I do want to include it.

In the sample query:

For "Head Office" I don't want to see "Area 3 NOT ABOVE" as the hideFromParentLevels is true in the edge

But if I swapped "Head Office" for "Saffron Walden" I do want to see it.

I hope the sample makes sense, please let me know if you have any questions!

For completeness here is the data:

```
g.addV('hierarchy').as('1').
  property(single, 'name', 'Head Office').
  property(single, 'type', 0).addV('hierarchy').
    as('2').
  property(single, 'name', 'Region 1').
  property(single, 'type', 1).addV('hierarchy').
    as('3').
  property(single, 'name', 'Area 1').
  property(single, 'type', 2).addV('hierarchy').
    as('4').
  property(single, 'name', 'Area 2').
  property(single, 'type', 2).addV('hierarchy').
    as('5').
  property(single, 'name', 'Area 3').
  property(single, 'type', 2).
  addV('communication').as('6').
  property(single, 'title', 'Communication A').
  addV('hierarchy').as('7').
  property(single, 'name', 'Saffron Walden').
  property(single, 'type', 3).addV('hierarchy').
    as('8').
  property(single, 'name', 'Brighton').
  property(single, 'type', 3).addV('hierarchy').
    as('9').
  property(single, 'name', 'St Albans').
  property(single, 'type', 3).addV('hierarchy').
    as('10').
  property(single, 'name', 'Southend on Sea').
  property(single, 'type', 3).addV('hierarchy').
    as('11').
  property(single, 'name', 'Cheltenham').
  property(single, 'type', 3).addV('hierarchy').
    as('12').
  property(single, 'name', 'South Harrow').
  property(single, 'type', 3).addV('hierarchy').
    as('13').
  property(single, 'name', 'Epsom').
  property(single, 'type', 3).addV('hierarchy').
    as('14').
  property(single, 'name', 'Dorking').
  property(single, 'type', 3).addV('hierarchy').
    as('15').
  property(single, 'name', 'Stevenage').
  property(single, 'type', 3).
  addV('communication').as('16').
  property(single, 'title', 'Area 3 NOT ABOVE').
  addE('child').from('1').to('2').addE('child').
  from('2').to('4').addE('child').from('2').
  to('5').addE('child').from('2').to('3').
  addE('child').from('3').to('10').
  addE('child').from('3').to('11').
  addE('child').from('3').to('12').
  addE('child').from('4').to('13').
  addE('child').from('4').to('14').
  addE('child').from('4').to('15').
  addE('child').from('5').to('9').addE('child').
  from('5').to('7').addE('child').from('5').
  to('8').addE('audience').from('6').to('7').
  property('hideFromParentLevels', false).
  addE('audience').from('6').to('8').
  property('hideFromParentLevels', false).
  addE('audience').from('6').to('9').
  property('hideFromParentLevels', false).
  addE('audience').from('16').to('7').
  property('hideFromParentLevels', true).
  addE('audience').from('16').to('8').
  property('hideFromParentLevels', true).
  addE('audience').from('16').to('9').
  property('hideFromParentLevels', true)
```

And here is my query:

```
g.V()
.has('name', 'Head Office')
.emit()
.repeat(__.out())
.in()
.hasLabel('communication')
.dedup()
.values('title')
```

I can filter on the hideFromParentLevels but not with a check on the vertex to see if the hierarchy is above or not.

Comment: Thanks for providing a sample data set, that makes things much simpler when trying to come up with a good answer. Are you looking to return the entire path or just the final title (as in the case of the example query)?

Comment: @KelvinLawrence just the final title or other properties from that vertex, not the path.

Comment: One other question, does the `type` property also reflect the level? In other words can the query just check against that property, or does the depth need to be calculated by looking back up the path as it were?

Comment: The type does reflect the depth level, but for the purposes of this question it is irrelevant and can be ignored - unless it's useful in someway?  I still need to check the hidefromparentlevels property in the edge somehow.